# Adding events to input on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I'm trying to add an event like 'keyup: validationSuccess' to all input fields on the checkout. I have overwritten input.html and added the Js to Shipping.js but now when i go to checkout/cart.html I get an error because of course the validationSuccess function doesn't exist on the Cart JS. So I need the function on all inputs on the Checkout but not on the Cart so overwriting input doesn't work. How do I do this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding new events you can subscribe to each input value as all those are knockoutjs observable elements

Comment: Do you maybe have an example of how I would to something like that?

Comment: yes @Sanne this is documented in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Ah thanks, hmm in the docs they do something like 'myViewModel.personName()' how would i do something like that in Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js? (i made a mixin for it) I'm unsure what how i could access the view model for that js.

Comment: I did see that you can access this.source.shippingAddress.firstname but i'm not sure if that is exactly what you mean?

Comment: you can subscribe to this input and get to know whenever value changes